# Xamarin.Forms with WCF

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, xamarin.forms

Usually I write a small topic with a question, but not today. I apologize in advance for "a lot of text", but this question exhausted me completely.

**The main task was to create Xamarin.Forms application and organize communication with the database through WCF**

Visual Studio 2015 pro, latest updates, Xamarin, latest updates.

Step 1.

This [link](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/web_services/walkthrough_working_with_WCF/) became the foundation of my decision. I created the WCF Service as specified in this topic. At first - without Configuring Remote Access to IIS Express.

> Add: WCF Service tested with Windows Forms Application. Test passed.

Step 2.

As I indicated earlier - Xamarin.Forms, not Xamarin.Android as in that topic. Here is my steps to create Xamarin.Forms project:

New Project - Cross-Platform - Cross Platform App(Xamarin.Forms or Native) -  Blank App(UI Technology) - Xamarin.Forms, Code Sharing Strategy - PCL(Portable Class Library)

Step 3.

The first problems: Default template for Xamarin.Forms in VS2015 includes target platforms incompatible with WCF. It means we can't add Service Reference to PCL while we have this target platforms. This problem took a lot of time, and my solutions are:

- **Delete From NuGet Xamarin.Forms - restart VS - Open PCL Properties - Click Change Target Platforms - Remove Windows Phone and Silverlight - restart VS - Add Xamarin.Forms NuGet - *the best one I found***
- **Rename packages.config to packages.config.BAK - do the same operation with changing platforms**

After one of this ways - "Add Service Reference" apears. The second way leads to crash VS when try to add service reference.

Step 4.

We can try to add Service Reference from VS as mentioned in guide from Xamarin site in " blue note " or generate Service client class with SLsvcUtil.exe

**My client side:**

```
public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        BasicHttpBinding binding = CreateBasicHttp();


        MyServiceClient client = new MyServiceClient(binding, new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:9607/MyService.svc"));
        client.DoWorkCompleted += Client_DoWorkCompleted;
        client.DoWorkAsync(10);

    }

    private void Client_DoWorkCompleted(object sender, DoWorkCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        var result = e.Result;
    }

    private static BasicHttpBinding CreateBasicHttp()
    {
        BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding
        {
            Name = "basicHttpBinding",
            MaxBufferSize = 2147483647,
            MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647
        };
        TimeSpan timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30);
        binding.SendTimeout = timeout;
        binding.OpenTimeout = timeout;
        binding.ReceiveTimeout = timeout;
        return binding;
    }
```

Step 5.

Run Service... Run Client... Wait for raise DoWorkComleted... get **System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException** in e.Result...

Anyone... Help me, please. This problem controls my life. I can't sleep, I can't eat... I just thinking about this ... problem...

[Link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gz9md064gi719aa/Projects.7z?dl=0) to my DropBox for source code.

> Fixed. The main problem: hocalhost for emulator isn't localhost for main workstation. Creating access for local network fixed my problem.

Comment: WCF configuration is complex. I suggest that you create a unit test (normal C# app, nothing to do with Xamarin) and make calls to your WCF service to make sure that your WCF service configuration is fine. Then you switch to troubleshooting the Xamarin project.

Comment: Edited my post. WCF was tested with Windows Forms app earlier

Comment: did you check the InnerException value?

Comment: Can't get to it. Appears in e.Result just jugged message. Maybe somewhere in generated service client class... not tested yet.

Comment: Checked for exception. Just edit my post